# Magento Fatal error: Class 'WP_ThemeGrayscale_Helper_Data' not found in.../app/Mage.php on line 546

Tags: magento

I can't access to my system> setting - i'm getting this error:
Fatal error: Class 'WP_ThemeGrayscale_Helper_Data' not found in.../app/Mage.php on line 546
, any suggestions ?

Comment: do u have that class?

Comment: check magento compliation is on or disable if on then disable it

Comment: it was the compliation status.. now it's works.. thanks guys!